# SCSS - Text in button won't center horizontally (text-align: center not working)

Tags: html, css, sass, bootstrap-4, slim-lang

[Mobile screen - width: 640px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh7Oi.png)
This is from a screen whose width is 640px. In screens bigger than this, the text in the button (e.g. "Add New") is centered horizontally.
I was hoping if someone can take a look at the SCSS and html.slim for this, and tell me how to fix this.

SCSS:

```
.card {
  @extend .col-sm-12, .col-md-12;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  border-width: 2px;

  a.btn {
    display: block;
    @extend .btn-sm, .btn-dark, .px-3;
    width:90px;
    max-width:100%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    float: right;
    margin: 3px -20px 3px -15px;
    text-shadow: none;
    opacity: 0.85;
    text-align: center;
    @media (max-width: 640px) {
      width: 37%;
      margin: 5px -35px 3px -15px;
      font-size: 100%;
    }
  }
```

html.slim:

```
.card
  .card-header
    h4=title
    a.btn href="#" Add New
  .card-body
    article
      strong Section Heading
      p.card-text Card Text Goes Here
      hr
    article
      strong Section Heading
      p.card-text Card Text Goes Here
      a.btn href="#" Click Here!
```

As you can see, I already have `text-align: center` but it doesn't seem to work when I set the width to be 37% for the screen whose width is equal or less than 640px (see the stuff below `@media (max-width: 640px)`). I came up with the number 37% for the width after trying out different numbers. Anything bigger than that number makes the button overlap with the text on the left side of the card (the container), and anything less than this would make the text not fit within the button.

For reference, I am also attaching a screenshot of how the buttons look when the screen is much bigger (e.g. iPhone X) and this is how I would like the buttons to look in a smaller screen too; Buttons stay in the containers, text fit and placed horizontally and vertically centered within the buttons.

[Mobile screen - width bigger than 640px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP9vi.png)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not an expert in Slim, but if I put your code in [a codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BrrWXr), it generates errors rather than outputting anything.

Comment: Looks like this has nothing to do with Slim and is of a CSS world. I suggest you edit your question and create a snippet (or codepen or jsfiddle) that demonstrates your issue